# Stop Rendering before data load using hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am new to react hooks I write a react custom hook

Hook:

```
 import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

 export const useFetch = (url, options) => {
 const [response, setResponse] = useState(null);
 const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
 const fetchData = async () => {
  try {
    const res = await fetch(url, options);
    const json = await res.json();
    setResponse(json);
  } catch (error) {
    setError(error);
  }
};
fetchData();
 }, []);
 return { response, error };
};
```

And I also write a functional component and i want component render when data comes
here is my component

Component

```
  import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
  import './index.scss';
  import { List } from '../components';
  import { useFetch } from '../../hooks';


export const Subscription = () => {
 const res = useFetch('http://localhost:8080/test', {});
 const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
 useEffect(() => {
   if (res.response.length > 0) {
    console.log('this is the test');
    setLoading(false);
   }
 });
const list = res.response;
return (
  <div>
    {isLoading && <div>Loading...</div>}
    {!isLoading && (
      <div className="list">
         <List subscriptions={list} />
      </div>
     )}
 </div>
 );
};
```

but i am unable to render List component I didn't understand once data comes from backend why list note having data still it having null value and lists is not renderd

I got proper values from backend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`useFetch` return `return { response, error };` ==> `const response = useFetch('http://localhost:8080/test', {});` the `response` is an object containing  `{ response, error }`

Do this instead `const {response} = useFetch('http://localhost:8080/test', {});`

And you should handle loading in `useFetch`

UseFetch

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export const useFetch = (url, options) => {
 const [response, setResponse] = useState(null);
 const [error, setError] = useState(null);
 const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
 useEffect(() => {
 const fetchData = async () => {
  try {
    const res = await fetch(url, options);
    const json = await res.json();
    setResponse(json);
    setLoading(false)
  } catch (error) {
    setError(error);
    setLoading(false)
  }
 };
 fetchData();
}, []);
 return { response, error,loading };
};
```

Subscription

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './index.scss';
import { List } from '../components';
mport { useFetch } from '../../hooks';


export const Subscription = () => {
 const {response: subscriptions, loading} = useFetch('http://localhost:8080/test', {});
return (
  <div>
    {isLoading && <div>Loading...</div>}
    {!isLoading && (
      <div className="list">
         <List subscriptions={subscriptions} />
      </div>
     )}
 </div>
 );
};
```